# PHP Form update will not update

Tags: php

I have written an Edit part of my Form but somehow it will not Update the edited Fields. The Code does not give any Errors but it will not update?!

If possible could somebody take a look please?

```
<?php
include "connect.php";//database connection

if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
  $id = intval($_GET["id"]);

  if (isset($_POST["edited"])) 
  {
    $update  = "UPDATE traumprojekt SET";
    $update .= sprintf("quantityProduct='%s', " , mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["quantityProduct"]));
    $update .= sprintf("titleProduct='%s', " , mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["titleProduct"]));
    $update .= sprintf("informationProduct='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["informationProduct"]));
    $update .= "WHERE id = '$id'";
    mysql_query($update);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `traumprojekt` WHERE id=$id";

  $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

  if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) 
  {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);


?>

<form method="post" action="edit_form.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">
  ID: <?php echo $row["id"] ?><br />
  Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantityProduct" value="<?php echo $row["quantityProduct"] ?>"><br />
  Product Title: <input type="text" name="titleProduct" value="<?php echo $row["titleProduct"] ?>"><br />
  Product Information: <input type="text" name="informationProduct" value="<?php echo $row["informationProduct"] ?>"><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="edited" value="1">
</form>

<?php

  }

}

?>
```

Comment: may be your getting mysql error somewhere echo mysql_error()  and your using old mysql use mysqli and new syntax

Comment: I am using MySQL Version: 5.5.24. Do you mean new Syntax for PHP?

Comment: debug your code and start with using `var_dump($update)`before committing it to mysql. Apart from that mysql_* is deprecated, you should move to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: ya new syntax for php